# How to prove a test $\hat{V}_{n}^{-1 / 2}\left(\hat{\theta}_{n}-\theta_{0}\right)>z_{\alpha}$ is consistent level $\alpha$ test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, consistency

I am doing exercise for exam revision but I don't know how to show what the question is asking, actually I am not sure how to reformulate the question itself to make it doable.

The question has two parts:

> Let $\hat{\theta}_{n}$ be an estimator of a real-valued parameter $\theta$ such that $V_{n}^{-1 / 2}\left(\hat{\theta}_{n}-
> \theta\right) \stackrel{L}{\rightarrow} N(0,1)$ for any $\theta$ and let $\hat{V}_{n}$ be a consistent estimator of $V_{n}$. Suppose that $V_{n} \rightarrow 0$.

> (i) Show that the test with rejection region
> $$
> \hat{V}_{n}^{-1 / 2}\left(\hat{\theta}_{n}-\theta_{0}\right)>z_{\alpha}
> $$
> is a consistent asymptotic level $\alpha$ test for testing $H_{0}: \theta \leq \theta_{0}$ versus $H_{1}: \theta>\theta_{0}$, where $z_{\alpha}$ is the $(1-\alpha)$ th quantile of $N(0,1)$.

> (ii) Apply the result in (i) to show that the one-sample one-sided $t$ -test
> for the testing problem in (i) is consistent asymptotic level $\alpha$ test.

---

My best guest for the second part is $t$-statistic is a standard normal divide by square root of $\chi^2(1)$ hence the one sample one sided t test is nothing but a direct application of the first question by central limit theorem: the expectation is estimated by sample average and the variance is estimated by sample standard deviation. But I don't know how to show the step in a rigorous manner.

For Part 1 of the question, I know a consent test need to satisfies:

> Consistent Test: A significance test of level $\alpha>0$ is called consistent if
> $$
> \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \beta_{n, \alpha}(\theta)=1
> $$
> for all $\theta \in \Omega_{1}$.

Where $\beta_{n, \alpha}(\theta):=P\left(\text { reject } H_{0} \mid \theta \in \Omega_{0} \cup \Omega_{1}\right)$.

In this particular question, this translates to

$\lim_np(\theta)=P(\hat{V}_{n}^{-1 / 2}\left(\hat{\theta}_{n}-\theta_0\right)>z_{\alpha})=1$ , here I implicitly assumes power function is a monotone increasing function in $\theta$ (which intuitively makes sense but I don't know how to prove it other than graphic), but I am stuck again.

To solve for the $P\left(\hat{V}_{n}^{-1 / 2}\left(\hat{\theta}_{n}-\theta_{0}\right)>c\right)=\alpha$, $c=z_\alpha$ (here I assume substituting $V_n^{-1/2 }$ by its consistent estimator won't affect the distribution, I am not sure if it's valid.) However here I am confused, it seems the value of the probability won't be affected by the sample size. The definition of consistent test is found [here](http://www.dliebl.com/RM_ES_Script/statistical-hypothesis-testing.html), if this is the correct definition I have to have made mistakes somewhere.

Could someone please help me to solve this question? I am very bad at transforming random variables and manipulating parameters under the expectation and probably. I am easily get lost whenever doing such an activity. I am hoping I could learning from this question as I have almost give all my thought in this question too.

Comment: Can you give the source of this question?  I think the correctness of the conclusion depends on the rates of $\hat{V}_n - V_n \to_P 0$ and $V_n \to 0$, it is probably not true if the former convergence rate is slower than the latter.

Comment: In addition, the statement "*$\hat{V}_n$ be a consistent estimator of $V_n$*" does not make much sense -- is $V_n$ a **fixed** parameter and converges to $0$? If so, why it varies with $n$?  If not, why it allows an "estimator"?